# Is there a way to get the list of resources deleted by shrinkResources?

Tags: android, shrinkresources

As the title states, is there a way to know what resources was deleted by shrinkResources?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this could be done!

You could read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) under **Troubleshoot resource shrinking**!

To check for deleted resources, `resources.txt` is generated under `<module-name>/build/outputs/mapping/release/`.

You could now see the used and deleted within this file.